# .htacess - rewrite rule - error client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I would like to ask for help.

I have this .htaccess file
The .htaccess file is used for redirect on example.com, when user enter another domain (which is also directed to this hosting). And then there are rules for "pretty URL addresses":

**example.com/advert/xx leads to example.com/advert.php?id=xx**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^advert/([^/]+)/?$ advert.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^adverts/([^/]+)/?$ adverts.php?kat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^adverts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adverts.php?kat=$1&podkat=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The problem is, that it causes errors like this:

> client denied by server configuration:
>   **/data/web/virtuals/56654/virtual/www/advert**

I think the server is looking into **FOLDER advert** which does not exist (it's only the pretty URL rule).

The support from hosting told me that my .htaccess file is wrong.
Could someone please tell me where am I wrong?

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Which url is causing the error?

Comment: "example.com/advert/xx" or "example.com/adverts/xx" or "example.com/adverts/xx/yy"

Answer (score 1):

Your first `RewriteCond` starts with `**`. Remove those or in case you want to comment out some lines, start those lines with a `#`. Same for your first `RewriteRule` at the end of the line.

Comment: No, that's only here, I wanted to make it strong/bold, but in the code it does not work.

Comment: Do you use PHP as FCGI? is `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` defined?

Comment: I am not sure, how will I recognize if %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} is defined?

Comment: Try replacing `SCRIPT_FILENAME` with `REQUEST_FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and having the RewriteRule include the DocumentRoot in the path resolved it for me.

This got denied:

```
RewriteRule ^/webapp/([\w]+) /script.cgi?id=$1
```

This worked:

```
RewriteRule ^/webapp/([\w]+) /var/www/html/script.cgi?id=$1
```

I do have directory permissions in my httpd.conf.  This may not be an issue if you're not using directory permissions.